# How to invoke maven default lifecycle

Tags: maven, lifecycle

If i call

```
mvn clean install
```

maven knows that clean is a lifecycle and install is a phase of the default lifecycle

if i call

```
mvn deploy
```

maven will execute all phases of the default lifecycle sequentially.

Is there a way to call the default lifecycle by giving a lifecyle name (instead of executing the last phsae of the lifecycle)?

EDIT: So the question is: is there a command

```
mvn lifecyclename
```

that start execution of the default lifecycle?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There seems to be a misunderstanding. Further reading could clarify that

```
mvn clean
```

does not invoke the whole clean lifecycle. In fact there is a clean phase in the clean lifecycle. And the command executes this phase and not the lifecycle.

Answer (score 8):

There is no command to run a lifecycle based on lifecycle name. So you **can't** do a `mvn Default` and expect it to run upto `Default:deploy`. You will have to mention a *task of a cycle* like `test`, `package`, `clean` and the life-cycle that owns this task will get active.

It does not make sense to have life-cycle as an argument. It will be confusing. For example running `mvn clean` is the Clean life-cycle or clean task?

Or, it will be more verbose to type `mvn clean` will run Clean life cycle; and `mvn clean:clean` will run Clean life cycle until `clean` task.

---

Maven has three life cycle. Executing a task (say task_N) of any of the life cycle will result in executing the whole life-cycle until that task (task_N). The three life cycles are *Clean*, *Default*, and *Site*.

For more details see here [Introduction to Maven Life-cycles and task order](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html)

You see when you execute say, `mvn test` these are the things gets executed in that order

> validate > initialize > generate-sources > process-sources > generate-resources > process-resources > compile > process-classes    > post-process  > generate-test-sources > process-test-sources > generate-test-resources > process-test-resources > test-compile > process-test-classes > test

You can't skip any of the default tasks. You may hook plugins that gets gets executed during a task.

Comment: What will happen if several phases have equally named phases?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know you cannot execute an isolated lifecycle phase.

But you can execute an isolated plugin goal .

```
mvn deploy:deploy
```

That won't trigger any plugin execution tied to `deploy` phase. But you can always add more plugin execution to the command line. So I better go with a profile skipping all plugins executions.

If you want to execute a `myplugin:mygoal` that was tied to `deploy` phase then

```
mvn myplugin:mygoal deploy:deploy
```

But the configuration of the execution must be in the cli.

But you better skip plugin executions that you do not want. only skip `test` and `integration-test` in command line. But you can achieve that with a profile that sets the configuration for the default cycle to skip.

```
<profiles>
  <profile>
    <id>skip</id>
      ...
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
            <skip>true</skip>
            </configuration>
          </plugin>
  ...
```

And then summon with

```
mvn deploy -Pskip
```

Comment: dunno how you refer to my question :-) i am looking for a command like "mvn lifecyclename" that starts the default lifecycle...

Comment: well, I though that  you wanted to skip some phases

Comment: ya... i am not a native english speaker :-(