# Phase name collisions in custom lifecycles in Maven?

Tags: maven, maven-lifecycle

AFAIK, you can create a custom build lifecycle in maven.

Also, AFAIK, you cannot tell maven to execute a *lifecycle*. You can either:

1. Tell maven to execute a *phase*: In this case, maven finds in which lifecycle this phase is, and then executes *all* phases in that lifecycle, up to the phase specified.
2. Tell maven to execute a goal, by specifying it as `mvn plugin_name:goal_name`

So, assume that I have created a custom lifecycle. And assume that this custom lifecycle has a phase named `install`.

When I write `mvn install`, will maven execute the default lifecycle (which has a phase named `install`) or my custom lifecycle (which also has a phase named `install`)?

How will maven determine which lifecycle to follow?

Comment: That's an interesting question. Note that it is also closely related to the packaging: a custom lifecycle would typically override the default lifecycle by declaring a new specific packaging. Thus `mvn install` would invoke the `install` phase of the lifecyle configured for that packaging. This does still leave the more general question (about `clean` and `site` lifecycles, that aren't tied to a packaging). Also related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11557638/1743880

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not supported (yet), though recently Stephen started a thread about it: http://maven.markmail.org/thread/z57dzgunecgfcrf7

Comment: Interesting (I feared it wasn't supported). Would it be possible to summarize what is being said in the emails in your answer? (in case the link dies).

Comment: We've identified that the current default (build-)lifecycle is often abused as a custom lifecycle and that it is hard quite hard to specify your own custom lifecycle. This should somehow be simplified and in case it is a widely used lifecycle, it should be added to Maven to become a new standard and to prevent a wide range of different lifecycles (compared to the targets of Ant)